# Inputting adjacency matrix from a file

Tags: java, file, file-io, java.util.scanner, adjacency-matrix

I am attempting to input the following file into my program in the form of an adjacency matrix.

```css
16
-1,1075,716,792,1425,1369,740,802,531,383,811,2211,661,870,999,772
1075,-1,1015,1770,2403,1662,870,1858,941,1426,1437,3026,1486,211,1463,314
716,1015,-1,928,1483,646,390,1085,185,749,530,2034,1377,821,471,772
792,1770,928,-1,633,1089,1111,246,908,409,495,1447,1317,1565,672,1470
1425,2403,1483,633,-1,9999,1630,752,1432,9999,931,814,1938,2198,1016,2103
1369,1662,646,1089,9999,-1,820,1335,832,9999,605,1839,2030,1468,421,1419
740,870,390,1111,1630,820,-1,1224,360,965,690,2197,1480,750,630,705
802,1858,1085,246,752,1335,1224,-1,1021,442,737,1566,1190,1653,918,1558
531,941,185,908,1432,832,360,1021,-1,685,496,2088,1192,736,616,656
383,1426,749,409,9999,9999,965,442,685,-1,738,1858,1938,1221,926,1126
811,1437,530,495,931,605,690,737,496,738,-1,1631,1472,1232,188,1152
2211,3026,2034,1447,814,1839,2197,1566,2088,1858,1631,-1,2752,2824,1563,2744
661,1486,1377,1317,1938,2030,1480,1190,1192,1938,1472,2752,-1,1281,1660,1183
870,211,821,1565,2198,1468,750,1653,736,1221,1232,2824,1281,-1,1269,109
999,1463,471,672,1016,421,630,918,616,926,188,1563,1660,1269,-1,1220
772,314,772,1470,2103,1419,705,1558,656,1126,1152,2744,1183,109,1220,-1
```

However, I think I have something wrong with my logic or I'm not using the Scanner correctly. This is my code:

```js
public class Tour 
{
 public static final int N = 16;
 public static final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 
 public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
          {
          if(adjMat[i][j] == INF)
           System.out.printf("%5s", 0);
          else
           System.out.printf("%5d", adjMat[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.println();
       }
    }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("american_tour.dat");
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        
        int[][] adjMat = new int[N][N];
            
            for(int i = 0, n = scanner.nextInt(); i < n; i++)
             for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
              adjMat[i][j] = n;
        
        
        scanner.close();
        printGrid(adjMat);
    }
}
```

Could someone show me how to properly input the data from the file into an adjacency matrix?

Comment: What is `N`?  Looks like you should be reading that from your file.

Comment: You need to give us more to work with than "I think something's wrong".  Are you getting an error or an exception somewhere, or is the output not what you expect?  Whichever one it is, please provide details.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code so that it includes int N and the print method. When I try to print the matrix, it's a matrix of all 16's.

Comment: Yup.  All 16's, because you call `nextInt` only once, in the initialization of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `data` does not respect a specific pattern for delimiters, try this instead :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("E:\\american_tour.dat");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    //N in the example equals 16
    int N = scanner.nextInt();

    //skip the first line
    scanner.nextLine();

    int[][] adjMat = new int[N][N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        String[] lines = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

        for (int j=0; j<lines.length; j++) {
            adjMat[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(lines[j]);
        }
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Nice attempt, but it won't work.  The data is mostly separated by commas, not white space.  You'd need to consume the interline commas after reading the integers, or use [`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) to include the comma.

Comment: @AJNeufeld i think it wont work neither with delimiter because lines does not end with `,` hence i used `scanner.nextLine()`

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s,]+");` would have been simpler.

Comment: I've posted an answer using the `useDelimiter()` method, for comparison. (And completeness)

Answer (score 1):

Improving Mouad's answer, using the scanner's built in support for custom delimiters:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s,]+");

int N = scanner.nextInt();
int[][] adjMat = new int[N][N];

for(int i=0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < N; j++) {
         adjMat[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

scanner.close();
```